# Get value from one sheet depending on value from another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In Sheet1 I have a Cell (H1) with the value 6. I want a different cell in Sheet1 to get the value at that position from sheet 2.. like this:

```
=Sheet2!A6
```

But I want the row it retrieves from to be different depending on the value of H1.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX():

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,H1)
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I also wanted the "A" to be dynamic. IE:

    =INDEX(Sheet2!J1:J1,H1) 

Where the value of cell J1 is A

Comment: That is not what was asked.  You would need to use the cardinal reference as the third criterion, so instead of `A` you would use `1`, `B=2`, `C=3`,... `=INDEX(Sheet2!A:Z,H1,J1)`

Comment: Of if you do not have too many you can use the volatile function: `=INDIRECT(J1 & H1)` which then you would put the letter column and number row.  But this is volatile which means it recalculates every time Excel recalculates.